# How to solve this logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms

I want so solve a problem:

for what values of a>0 does the equation a^x=x have solutions?

I have started to write it like a^logx=x. But its tricky this one. Does anyone have an idea of how to find the solutions?

Comment: why don't you try assessing the first derivative? :)

Comment: Is it clear to you that there must be a constant $c>1$ such that there are solutions exactly when $0<a\le c$?

Comment: yes thank u i will start with that! @llis

Comment: this is all i know about the funktion @HenningMakholm

Comment: @Fanny: When you say "this" do you mean what I just wrote?

Comment: @HenningMakholm i mean to me its not clear that there is such a boundary

Comment: @HenningMakholm or I guess It must be if the problem is to find that constant value c

Comment: @Fanny: Sonnhard's answer shows how to do that (it is somewhat hard to read, but the actual calculations are straightforward).

Comment: @HenningMakholm okej! im not so great with logarithms so i guess best to get to some simpler examples first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would write your equation like follows:
$$\ln(a)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$ and now we define $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$ for $$x>0$$ we get $$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}$$ we find $$f'(x)=0$$ if $$x=e$$ and $$f(e)=\frac{1}{e}$$ and $$f(e)$$ is the Maximum of f(x). Nowe we get
if $$-\infty<y\le 0 $$ our equation has only one solution. If $$1<y<\frac{1}{e}$$ our equation has two Solutions. If $$y=\frac{1}{e}$$ our equation has exactly one solution and if $$y>\frac{1}{e}$$ our equation has no solution. Note that $$y=f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$